# Need help on REGEXP_SUBSTR() function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a query which gets the results from a column string which is between `>` and `<\`

Query is written as

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Column','([^>]+)\</', 1, 1,NULL,1) from table
```

I understand 3rd parameter is the start position
4th is for occurrence

But not sure on 5th and 6th

Can any one explain how this query is working. I have looked at few blogs but the parameters are different.

what is `([^>]+)\</`   , `Null` (5th) and `1` (6th)

Comment: [Literally second link in google for `REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-string-functions/oracle-regexp_substr/). 5th: no flags should be applied for this regex match, 6th: return group (content of parentheses) number 1

Comment: `([^>]+)\</` is a regex. You can see what is a regex, and what does all this mean [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: It is clearly described in the documentations, which is the most reliable source of information: [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099). Moreover, it has additional links to explanations, examples etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is wrong and will not match "results from a column string which is between `>` and `<\`" as it never matches an initial `>`.

If you want to match between those then you need to include the leading `>` and then you can just match as few characters as possible (using the non-greedy pattern `[^<>]*?`) until you find `</` (in the description you state `\` and in the code you use `/`. I assume you want `/` as that is used in XML):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
         'Column',
         '>([^<>]*?)</',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       )
FROM   table_name
```

As for:

> what is `([^>]+)\</`, `Null` (5th) and `1` (6th)

The regular expression is incorrect as it will match one-or-more non-`>` characters until it finds the first `</` sub-string.

The parameters are described in [Oracle's `REGEXP_SUBSTR` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) and are the `match_param` and `subexp` arguments. A complete description is available in the documentation but your arguments will use the default match parameters and return the contents of the first capturing group.

---

#### However

If you are really parsing XML (or XHTML) then you would be better using a proper XML parser such as [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm).

Comment: Thanks @MT0 , Script provided above is actually working in my environment. I am a beginner in pl sql so wanted to understand how it actually works.

Yes , File is XML. I have tried to use XMLTABLE but the prob is database is in different server and i dont have access to it. I see XMLTABLE works fine by creating a directory and then placing the file in the location. With the knowledge i have, I was not able to achieve the requirement by passing the xml file contents to XMLTABLE so created a SQL custom query